# How to print image in output stream?

Tags: progress-4gl

Is it possible to print some text + image with 4GL? I tried several approaches and nothing works for me. My code is below

```
DEFINE VARIABLE mMyMemPtr AS MEMPTR NO-UNDO.
FILE-INFO:FILE-NAME = "C:\image.png".
SET-SIZE(mMyMemPtr) = FILE-INFO:FILE-SIZE.
INPUT FROM VALUE(FILE-INFO:FILE-NAME) BINARY NO-MAP NO-CONVERT.
IMPORT mMyMemPtr.
INPUT CLOSE.

OUTPUT STREAM printstream TO PRINTER.
PUT "some text: " AT 1 SKIP.
PUT mMyMemPtr.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

[image: Error code]

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It's possible to print images with ABL/Progress 4GL but not that way. You will need some other technique. The easiest way is probably to look into some kind of document format that supports printing. For example creating and printing:

- a Word document via ActiveX automation (start here: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P20445)
- an HTML document
- a PDF (there are freeware PDF-tools for Progress like the outdated http://www.oehive.org/pdfinclude.html - possibly others as well) or PostScript document
- Via any report generator like Crystal, Eclipse BIRT etc.